# Can you SWIG a boost::optional<>?

Tags: c#, c++, boost, swig

I've been using SWIG successfully to build a wrapper interface to make my C++ libraries available in C#.  Recently I exposed some `boost::optional<>` objects and SWIG is having problems with them.  Is there a standard way to deal with this?  Someone must have run into this before...

Comment: Is this not a broader question on how SWIG deals with templates? I've not used SWIG, but a quick scan suggest there may be some limitations wrt templates.

Comment: @dotcomslashnet Yes and no.  SWIG can be configured to customize the way it translates/wraps just about anything.  I was hoping that both SWIG and `boost::optional<>` are widely-enough used that someone has done this already so I don't have to re-invent the wheel.  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since SWIG doesn't understand boost types, typemaps have to be written.  Here's a pair of typemaps for `boost::optional<int>`.

From Python, `None` or an integer can be passed into a function:

```
%typemap(in) boost::optional<int> %{
    if($input == Py_None)
        $1 = boost::optional<int>();
    else
        $1 = boost::optional<int>(PyLong_AsLong($input));
%}
```

A returned `boost::optional<int>` will be converted to a None or a Python integer:

```
%typemap(out) boost::optional<int> %{
    if($1)
        $result = PyLong_FromLong(*$1);
    else
    {
        $result = Py_None;
        Py_INCREF(Py_None);
    }
%}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll have to adapt it for C# instead of Python, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Oops, completely missed your C# tag, but it should be a small change.

Answer (score 3):

A possible C# solution using std::vector

```
#if SWIGCSHARP

// C++
%typemap(ctype) boost::optional<int32_t> "void *"
%typemap(out) boost::optional<int32_t> %{

    std::vector<int32_t> result_vec;
    if (!!$1)
    {
        result_vec = std::vector<int32_t>(1, $1.get());
    }
    else
    {
        result_vec = std::vector<int32_t>();
    }

    $result = new std::vector< uint32_t >((const std::vector< uint32_t > &)result_vec); 
%}

// C#
%typemap(imtype) boost::optional<int32_t> "global::System.IntPtr"
%typemap(cstype) boost::optional<int32_t> "int?"
%typemap(csout, excode=SWIGEXCODE) boost::optional<int32_t> {
    SWIG_IntVector ret =  new SWIG_IntVector($imcall, true);$excode

    if (ret.Count > 1) {
        throw new System.Exception("Return vector contains more then one element");
    }
    else if (ret.Count == 1) { 
        return ret[0]; 
    }
    else { 
        return null; 
    }
}

#endif //SWIGCSHARP
```

Comment: This solution works on my side. @hugo24 do you have the typemap for the input part also?

Comment: @masphei I don't have the input part yet.

Comment: How can I use `SWIG_IntVector`? In the generated `.cs` file I get the error
`error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SWIG_IntVector' could not be found`

Comment: @bleuj I think that you have to at least once before that swig a std::vector<int32_t>